# The peculiar properties of 14732

Tags: elementary-number-theory, universal-property

About a year ago, I delved into the properties of the number 14732. A number that have popped into my brain at random times for well over a decade.

Through a bit of experimenting with base10 and base2, I was able to extrapolate some properties of the number 14732, which I will list below.

Not knowing how to proceed to find other numbers with the same, or similar, properties, I sent my findings to Matt Parker, whom you might know from Numb3rphile on youtube.

He was suitable interested, and suggested that I post my findings here, if I hoped to find help in finding other such numbers, or determine if 14732 is unique.

It's been a busy year since, but I've finally gotten around to posting here, asking for help in finding other similar numbers, or even better, an explanation of why 14732 behaves in the way outlined below.

I would have liked to include the math formulas for each property, but since I am not skilled in complex algebra, I have been unable to do so.

### Questions

- Is 14732 unique for all of the below six properties?
- If other numbers share all six properties, is there then a shared pattern that can be used to find other numbers?
- Are there any numbers that only satisfy the first five properties, but not the sixth?

#### First property

When representing the number (D1) in base2 (B1), it can be split into two halves of equal length (H1 and H2), each of which is a direct bit-for-bit opposite of the other.

**Proof**

```
D1 = 14732
B1 = 11100110001100

H1 = 1110011
H2 = 0001100
```

#### Second property

When H1 and H2 are added together in decimal (DH1 and DH2), they form a multiplicative (M) of D1.

**Proof**

```
DH1 = 1110011 => 115
DH2 = 0001100 => 12

M = DH1 + DH2
M = 115 + 12
M = 127

14732 / 127 = 116
```

#### Third property

When inverting B1, the result (B2) can be converted back to decimal (D2), which will also be a multiplicative of M.

**Proof**

```
B1 = 11100110001100
B2 = 00011001110011

D2 = B2 => 1651

1651 / 127 = 13
```

#### Fourth property

Subtracting D1 from D2 yields a third result (D3), which is also a multiplicative of M.

**Proof**

```
D3 = D1 - D2
D3 = 14732 - 1651
D3 = 13081

13081 / 127 = 103
```

#### Fifth property

Converting D3 to base2 (B3), inverting the bits (B4), and back to decimal (D4) results in 2D2.

**Proof**

```
B3 = 11001100011001
B4 = 00110011100110
D4 = B4 => 3302

D4 = 2D2
3302 = 2D2
3302 = 2 * (1651)
```

#### Sixth property

Reversing D2 to get D5, and subtracting D5 from D2, then multiplying by M, and adding D4 results in the starting number (D1)

**Proof**

```
D5 = 1651 => 1561

D1 = (D2 - D5) * M + D4
D1 = (1651 - 1561) * 127 + 2D2
D1 = (90) * 127 + 2 * (1651)
D1 = 11430 + 3302
D1 = 14732
```

Comment: Have you tried to write a computer program (e.g. in Python) to check (e.g.) the first 10 million numbers for these properties?

Comment: Adding to what @rtybase said, I would suggest that you label your properties $P1$ to $P6$ and assign a truth value bit to each. You can compute a six bit binary number for each of the first $N$-million numbers using your program. The numbers can be converted to decimals in the range $[0,127]$. Clearly, $14732$ will have the value $127$, but if you can see if any other number also yields this value (and that number may be even lower than $14732$, which would be most interesting to you, I think). You can also look at other combinations of properties using the (sorted) values you've computed.

Comment: @rtybase I have, yes. Working as a software developer, such was my first attempt. However, I got stumped on the conversions from base10 to base2, and how to store a number in base2.

Comment: @mireigi It's been a long time since I've done any programming (I used to do electronics and computing as a hobby in my younger days) - so I'm not sure about Python or more modern languages, but a language like C certainly has tools for these. I think even an Excel sheet can handle things like this, though it'll probably be computationally inefficient.

Comment: Try Python, it's easy to learn. C is a bit of overkill for such tasks ... start with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/699866/python-int-to-binary

Comment: @Deepak The only languages that I'm confident for such an approach are C#. If it has some tools for doing stuff with other bases than base10, they would be external languages. It's late here (0200 am), so I'll follow that line of thought tomorrow. Thanks for the suggesions so far.

Comment: Or this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1838963/easy-and-fast-way-to-convert-an-int-to-binary

Comment: Properties $2,3,4,5$ are more or less trivial consequence of property $1$. We can forget them. Only property $6$ is non-trivial. If my program is correct, there are no other solution for $D_1 < 2^{48}$.

Comment: @achillehui I have tested for only property 6 as well, and also found the number 2 to fit that property, but no others. My limit was only 10^9, however. Did you miss that in your results, or was it never among them?

Comment: @mireigi I never tested two bit numbers. My test start from four bits.

Answer (score 1):

Much too long for a comment: Let's try to write it algebraically. I'm not distinguishing between $d_1$ and $b_1$ because a number *is the same number* no matter how we choose to write it down.

**Property 1**. Let $n$ be the number of bits in each half of your number. Presumably $h_2$ must start with a zero such that your entire $d_1$ does *not* have a leading zero bit. That is,
$$ 0 \le h_2 < 2^{n-1} $$
Whenever we choose a $h_2$ we can get everything else. Flipping the bits of $h_2$  produces $$ h_1 = (2^n-1)-h_2 $$
and then
$$ d_1 = 2^nh_1 + h_2 = 2^n(2^n-1)-2^nh_2 + h_2 = (2^n-1)(2^n-h_2) $$

**Property 2.** Adding $h_1$ and its bit-for-bit flip produces a string of $n$ ones, which is
$$ m = 2^n-1 $$
(This is how I computed $h_1$ above in the first place).
As we see, this is automatically a factor of $d_1$.

**Property 3.** Inverting $d_1$ is the same as subtracting it from a string of $2n$ ones, which is $2^{2n}-1$ and also happens to equal $m(2^n+1)$ (because $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(a+b)$, here with $a=2^n$ and $b=1$). This produces
$$ d_2 = m(2^n+1) - d_1 = m(2^n+1) - m(2^n-h_2) = m(h_2+1) $$
which automatically has $m$ as a factor.

**Property 4.** We get
$$ d_3 = d_1 - d_2 =  m(2^n-h_2) - m(h_2+1) = m(m-2h_2)$$
again of course a multiple of $m$ since it is the difference of two such multiples.

**Property 5.** Inverting $d_3$ is again a matter of subtracting it from $m(2^n+1)$:
$$ d_4 = m(2^n+1) - m(m-2h_2) = m(2^n+1 - m + 2h_2) = m(2+2h_2) = 2m(h_2+1) = 2d_2 $$

So properties 2, 3, 4, 5 follow automatically once we have chosen $n$ and $h_2$ to create a $d_1$ that satisfies property 1 (as already noted by @achille hui).

**Property 6.** Here it gets complicated, because reversing the sequence of decimal digits of a number is not an algebraic operation. But let's see what we can do. You specify
$$ d_1 = (d_2-d_5)m + d_4 $$
which first of all is the same as
$$ m(2^n-h_2) = (m(h_2+1)-d_5)m + 2m(h_2+1) $$
so we can cancel the $m$s and rearrange to
$$ d_5 = mh_2 + m + 3h_2+2 - 2^n $$
which simplifies further to
$$ d_5 = (2^n+2)h_2 + 1 $$

---

**All in all**, we're looking for $n$ and $h_2<2^{n-1}$ such that
$$ d_2 = (2^n-1)(h_2+1) \qquad\text{and}\qquad d_5 = (2^n+2)h_2 + 1 $$
have reverse digit sequences as decimal representations.

In your number we have $n=7, h_2=12$, so
$$ d_2 = 127\cdot 13 = 1651 \\
d_5 = 130\cdot12 + 1 = 1561 $$

Comment: That is some impressive work you put into it. I have tested D1 < 10^9 using your formula for property 6, and it came up with the numbers 2, and 14732. Using the suggestion from @deepak I managed to get all the properties written into simple rules, using their results for the calculations in the next properties, and checked with the same limit for D1 again. The number 2 satisfies all the properties, except for the fifth. 14732 satisfies all. I prefer your final formula for checking, but if it is derived from the others, there might be something that is missing. Do you have any idea what it is?

Comment: @mireigi: How does $d_1=2$ not satisfy property 5? I get $d_2=1$, $d_3=1$, $d_4=2$.

Comment: I think I see what's going on. In your formula you are using $d_3$, when it should be $b_3$. Inverting a decimal, and inverting a binary yields two very different results, when the binary is converted back into decimal.

Comment: @mireigi: As far as you have described $d_i$ and $b_i$ are **the same number**. A number is what it is, no matter how you choose to write it down.

Comment: (edit: moving to a separate entry. Too long for a comment).

Answer (score 0):

I think we've got it mixed up then.
When I'm writing about inverting the bits, I mean flipping them, so 0 becomes 1, and 1 becomes 0.
The formula for that is this: $b_i = (2^{n_2}-1) - b$, where $n_2$ is the length of the binary number, and $2^{n_2}-1$ is converted to binary.

From the top:

#### Prop 1

$d_1 = 2$

$b_1 = 10$

$h_1 = 1$

$h_2 = 0$

#### Prop 2

$dh_1 = 1$

$dh_2 = 0$

$m = 1 + 0 = 1$

#### Prop 3

$b_2 = 2^{n_2}-1 - b_1 = 2^2-1 - 10 = 11 - 10 = 01$

$d_2 = 1$

#### Prop 4

$d_3 = d_1 - d_2 = 2 - 1 = 1$

#### Prop 5

$b_4 = (2^{n_2}-1) - b_3 = 2^1-1 = 1 - 1 = 0$

$d_4 = b_4 = 0$

$d_4 = 2(d_3)$

$0 = 2$